# Ensure a QByteArray owns its memory (QByteArray::fromRawData)

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

Say we have a function store

```
void store(const QByteArray& data);
```

This function's job is to take `data` and store it away. Unfortunately, it is not safe to do that if the argument was created with `QByteArray::fromRawData(ptr, size)`, because it and all its copies require that `ptr` remains valid.

Therefore `store` has no option to forbid its callers to pass in such an array, to treat `data` as if it was a `const char*` on stereoids or to force a deep-copy with `detach`. All of this is not satisfying and especially the latter hurts performance because if `data` was COW-copied before being passed to `store`, we will be doing an unnecessary deep-copy.

`QByteArray` has a `private` function `nulTerminated` whose implementation seems to do just what I want: If it doesn't own the memory, it deep copies. And if it owns the memory, it does nothing but return `*this`.

Two questions really

- Is there a work-around using `public` facilities?
- The Qt docs mention that `ptr` must only be alive for the lifetime of the return value and any copies of it. If you say `.right(.size())`, it would seem this is not a copy, so Qt would need to make a deep copy according to the docs. But does it really do so?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source (for example [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.cpp.html#_ZNK10QByteArray5rightEi)), `ba.right(ba.size());` is actually plain shallow copy, almost a no-op, so that's not a solution for you. And in any case, relying on any behaviour not backed by documentation is a bit unsafe, it could be changed without notification in future Qt versions.

That being said, [`QByteArray::detach()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h.html#_ZN10QByteArray6detachEv) is undocumented but public. It will perform deep copy on arrays created with `fromRawData()`, but not on already unshared data, and I *think* this is unlikely to change. Demonstration:

```
QByteArray ba1 = QByteArray::fromRawData("foo", 4);
QByteArray ba2("foo");
qDebug() << (void*)ba1.constData() << (void*)ba2.constData();
ba1.detach(); ba2.detach();
qDebug() << (void*)ba1.constData() << (void*)ba2.constData();
```

Output of above for example:

```
0x804b960 0x93ebfd8
0x93d2170 0x93ebfd8
```

---

Looking at the source, [`IS_RAW_DATA` macro](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.cpp.html#_M/IS_RAW_DATA) is in the *qbytearray.cpp* file, and I did not spot any way that you could take advantage of it using public interface. So, to do what you want seems to not be possible, and `detach()` is the closest you can get, even `QByteArray::squeeze()` doesn't detach raw data.

Comment: But as I understand it, it will also deep copy `QByteArray a("hello"); QByteArray b = a; b.detach();` which is not desired.

Comment: So I guess i need to hack into it with the private-access hack and call the nulTerminate function. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

this sounds more like a conceptual problem, rather than technical.

`store()` tries to take absolute ownership, but **"taking ownership" on a QByteArray  does not make much sense conceptually**. A copy might share its memory with another, or it might not, or it might be created from raw data, so there's a hidden ownership juggle going on under the hood and the whole class *is designed to hide this from you*. The whole implicit sharing thing doesn't mesh well with modern explicit ownership transfer paradigm in general, and QByteArray complicates matters further by providing the raw data facility.

If possible, accepting a non-implicitly-shared container that holds absolute ownership over their content (such as std::string, which is easily generated with QByteArray::toStdString()) by rvalue, forcing callers to copy, would be the best option.